# Permanent and global variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie so please excuse my lingo.

I am running the following codes in two pieces:

```
select * from #table1
where date between 20120101 and 20120131

select * from #table2
where date between 20120101 and 20120131
```

I have many such small snippets which I must run individually so that I can see the results of each run. But I am kind of getting sick of changing the date every month when I need to do it.

So, I was wondering if there is something of following sort:

```
declare startdate = 20120101
declare enddate = 20120131

select * from #table1
where date between startdate and enddate

select * from #table2
where date between startdate and enddate
```

The idea is that I would once declare the `startdate` and `enddate` variables I can then run the remaining select statements without having to update each of them individually.

Comment: now that you are doing variables, look into stored procedures and passing in parameters, and you won't have to edit the SQL at all.  you can do `EXEC YourQueryProcedure 20120101,20120131`

Answer (score 7):

You're very close. Just need to clean up the syntax a bit. Variables are declared with an "@" sign and a datatype.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
SET @startdate = '2012-01-01'

DECLARE @enddate DATETIME
SET @enddate = '2012-01-31'

SELECT * FROM #table1
WHERE date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate

SELECT * FROM #table2
WHERE date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

As a side note, be careful when using BETWEEN with date tests, as it can be confusing since each date defaults to a time of midnight. So, as written, you'll not find any records on '2012-01-31' after midnight. It's better, IMHO, to be explicit here by bumping your end date up by one day and testing like this:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
SET @startdate = '2012-01-01'

DECLARE @enddate DATETIME
SET @enddate = '2012-02-01'

SELECT * FROM #table1
WHERE date >= @startdate 
  AND date <  @enddate
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running all of these in one script,

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2012-01-01'
declare @enddate datetimg = '2012-01-31'
```

(SQL Server 2008+)

Comment: Just a note, that assuming SQL Server, this will only work in 2008+. Otherwise, you will need to do the declare and set on separate lines (as Joe did). I cannot speak for other versions of SQL